# Drag And Drop SharePoint WebParts in Mozilla FireFox

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, sharepoint-2010, web-parts

i am having a problem with drag and drop of Share-point web-parts in browsers other than I.E.

the drag and drop of Share-point web-parts in internet explorer works fine . but in any other browser it ll not work . i don't know the way to enable it in .

is there any way to make drag and drop of Share-point web-parts ,cross browser compatible.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I think the drag and drop is a active x control and it is only useable with the Internet Explorer.